# All .exe files try to open with the wrong program

Tags: windows-10

I'm not sure how I managed to ask my computer to open all .exe files in VAST Lite (a segmentation program I recently installed), but that caused every program I tried to start to just open VAST.

I've managed to remove VAST from my machine now, so now instead of opening every program in VAST, I just get a popup asking me "How do you want to open this .exe file?" when I try to open ANY program.

How can I revert this? To be clear, I am currently unable to open most programs because of this.

**I cannot open task manager, command prompt, registry editor, McAfee, etc.**

I am able to open the command prompt by restarting my computer and holding shift, then going to advanced troubleshooting and opening the command prompt, but I can't figure out what to do from there. I've tried entering `assoc .exe=exefile` but that didn't seem to make any difference.

To the mod that closed this question: The link you referred me to is for windows-7 and none of those solutions work for my problem. Please re-open my question!

Comment: Run your Anti Virus app and check for viruses.

Comment: I can't open mcafee for the same reasons unfortunately. I'll include that in my question.

Comment: You are at a point of backing up the drive (by any possible means) and then reinstalling windows.